# Using deinit to make a save to database

Tags: swift

Very junior dev, so excuse the question but I'm just curious. I have a local database and I'm considering using a ViewModel to store the information which will only be persisted if the user hits the *save* button.

But if they send the app to background for example and forgot about the app, can I use the deinit to make the saves the database?

Now not considering the user experience in this case, I just would like to know if this method is ever used.

Comment: I've never even used `deinit`. It's probably better to listen to AppDelegate/SceneDelegate methods ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There is no promise that `deinit` will ever be called. It should not be relied on for anything other than freeing resources held by the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app lifecycle is unpredictable enough that you can't trust `deinit` will be called.

When your app is sent to the background it has a few seconds to run before it's frozen, if the user doesn't use it in a while it will be killed silently, and `deinit` won't be called.

If the user kills the app, I don't think `deinit` is called either.

Like it was suggested in the comments, you should listen to life cycle events and react to those. It will change depending on how your app is setup:

UIKit + UIApplication Delegate: implement [applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground)

UIKit + Scene Delegate: implement [sceneDidEnterBackground(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197917-scenedidenterbackground)

Full SwiftUI: Observe changes of [Scene Phase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenephase)

Comment: You're correct that `deinit` is not called if the app is killed (this is most common on iOS). On platforms where the app can terminate normally (macOS, Linux), `deinit` is generally not called either.